# Set dynamic html code into iframe without scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

How can i set html code into iframe when height and width of html increased but iframe area is fixed.

Issue found when increase height and width of html then iframe area changed into scrolling iframe.
 htmlCode.html :

```
<div class="dots"><img  src="mirror3.png" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
```

.dots {border: 30px solid transparent; border-image-source: url(frame3.png);border-image-repeat: round;border-image-slice: 30;height: 100px;width: 200px;}

Requirement: whenever increase the size of html then it fit into iframe. Actually I want to set html code into 80 % of iframe area no matter what is the height and width of html.

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest you is that you can figure out which part in the iframe is too much dynamic i mean that which part changes and the changes is hugh in terms of content so that you can fix its height and width and use a scroller for that particular part using css property overflow-y:auto;.

I am not sure what exactly is the content in the iframe so i am supposing it to be some description content.

Sorry if i don't meet up to your expectations.